# How would you unit test data annotations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, data-annotations

Two of the class properties have the following annotations:

```
    [Key]
    [Column]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I understand that testing Key, Column and Required attributes is no longer a unit test, it's an integration test as it would depend on the underlying database, but how do you go about testing MaxLength(25) attribute?

One of the alternatives that I can think of, is to add a code contract into the property.

**Update**

As suggested, I wrote the following helper:

```
    public class AttributeHelper <T> where T : class
    {
        private Type GivenClass 
        { 
            get { return typeof (T); }
        }

        public bool HasAnnotation(Type annotation)
        {
            return GivenClass.GetCustomAttributes(annotation, true).Single() != null;
        }

        public bool MethodHasAttribute(Type attribute, string target)
        {
           return GivenClass.GetMethod(target).GetCustomAttributes(attribute, true).Count() == 1;
        }

        public bool PropertyHasAttribute(Type attribute, string target)
        {
            return GivenClass.GetProperty(target).GetCustomAttributes(attribute, true).Count() == 1;
        }

    }
```

I have then tested my helper:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThisMethod_Has_TestMethod_Attribute()
    {
        // Arrange
        var helper = new AttributeHelper<AttributeHelperTests>();

        // Act
        var result = helper.MethodHasAttribute(typeof (TestMethodAttribute), "ThisMethod_Has_TestMethod_Attribute");

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
```

Everything works fine, apart from the fact that methods and properties must be public in order for me to use reflection. I can't think of any cases where I had to add attributes to the private properties/methods.

And then testing the EF annotations:

```
        public void IdProperty_Has_KeyAttribute()
        {
            // Arrange
            var helper = new AttributeHelper<Player>();

            // Act
            var result = helper.PropertyHasAttribute(typeof (KeyAttribute), "Id");

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }
```

Comment: I think by testing that the attributes do their job rather than testing the underlying business logic you are testing the attribute framework and that is not what you should be testing (that was done by Microsoft already). All you want is in your business layer to ensure if you pass a string 26 chars long that the method returns some sort of violation cause 25 is the max length. You write a unit test against your business layer passing a string of 26 chars. If you want to test your UI layer not allowing more than 25 chars to be entered use Selenium for that or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I understand that testing Key, Column and Required attributes is no longer a unit test, it's an integration test as it would depend on the underlying database

How is that so? You can test whether `Id` property is marked with all those attributes just fine. And it falls into unit-test category.

```
[Test]
public void Id_IsMarkedWithKeyAttribute()
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Id");

    var attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true)
        .Cast<KeyAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.That(attribute, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

This way you can assure your properties are marked with any attribute you can think of. Sure, this involves some reflection work but that's how you test attribute marking.

Comment: That's very helpful, I haven't looked at it from in this way. I thought that I'd have to validate that attributes work by talking to the database and checking whether constraints and checks have been enforced. Hence why I said it's an integration test.

Comment: @CodeWorks: of course integration test would verify presence of those attributes too. But there's one major drawback - you don't run integration tests as often as you do unit tests. Plus, they take much longer to run. Since marking your properties with those attributes is a *contract*, that should be unit tested like any other contract. Long story short - the best way is to have two sets of tests.

Comment: Just wrote some unit tests for the suggested helper. Reflection will work only for public properties.