# How to write failed unit test case for controller actions with Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, authorization

My current structure of my application is -

MyController class is below that uses MyRepository class shown below.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public MyController() : this(new MyRepository())
    {
    }
    public MyController(MyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _repository.GetAllItems();
        if (items.Count() == 0)
             return View("EmptyItems");
        else
        {
             return View("List", items);
        }
    }
}
```

MyRepository class is below.

```
public class MyRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly TodoDbContext _dbcontext;
    private readonly ISecurityService _securityService;


    public MyRepository() : this(new TestDbContext(), new SecurityService())
    {                        
    }
    public MyRepository(TestDbContext context, ISecurityService securityService)
    {
        _dbcontext = context;
        _securityService = securityService;
    }
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAllItems()
    {
         var userid = _securityService.GetUser();
         var list = _dbcontext.TotalItems.Where(e => e.UserId == userid);

         return list;
    }
}
```

Unit test method is below -

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexAction_Should_Return_View_For_AllItems()
{
    //Arrage            
    var controller = MyController();

    //Act
    var result = controller.Index();

    //Asset
    Assert.IsNotNull(result as ViewResult);
}
```

The unit test method shown above always succeeds. It is not checking if the user is authenticated or not. How do I write a unit test case that checks if the user is actually authenticated using Moq etc.
I am new to MVC so any detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have reordered the code as advised. Could someone please reply to my question ? I am very new to MVC so any response would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need not to test the functionality of Authorize attribute.That is already tested in the framework.You should only check the logic of you controller works or not.Rest assured that if user is not authorized it will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write a unit test case that checks if the user is actually authenticated using Moq etc.

**You don't!** Logic behind `[Authorize]` is part of ASP.NET source code. It is tested by ASP.NET team at Microsoft. This is not your code which means you **should not be testing it**.

What you can do is write a test that would check whether your controller's methods are marked with such attribute (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260017) for ideas). Such tests will give you sort of assurance that you didn't forget to mark cruicial methods with this attribute.

However, your prime unit testing focus should be on `Index` method itself - what it does and how it works. In your case you want to verify what sort of view is returned basing on whether there are any items in repository (note that you need to pass `IRepository` rather than `MyRepository` to controller's constructor in order to mock it).