# How do I test if a property has required annotation?

Tags: c#, .net

I have property defined like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="The Year of Manufacture has to be filled")]
public int? YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
```

How do I write Unit test, which tests, if the property has set the required Annotation?

Comment: What would happen if it did not have it? Make that happen and check it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259793/how-would-you-unit-test-data-annotations

Comment: What's the point of writing a unit test for that?

Comment: going to accept any of these answers?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) for this, which allows you to do this very cleanly:

```
typeof(MyType)
    .GetProperty("YearOfManufacture")
    .Should()
    .BeDecoratedWith<RequiredAttribute>("because MyType.YearOfManufacture is required.");
```

Comment: I don't like this test at all: the property name is weakly typed as a string and it tests an explicit implementation (attribute decoration). What if the validation is done through a different system, like fluent validation rules? No change in functionality yet all the tests break.

Comment: Fair points and definitely worth mentioning. One *might* invoke YAGNI on future-proofing it against switching validation frameworks, but it depends on the larger context. I went for a succinct answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a test helper method that will run the validation on a particular instance of your view model:

```
public bool TryValidate(object model, out ICollection<ValidationResult> results)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    return Validator.TryValidateObject(
        model, context, results, validateAllProperties: true
    );
}
```

and then in your unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void YearOfManufacture_Is_Required()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new MyViewModel();
    sut.YearOfManufacture = null;
    ICollection<ValidationResult> results;

    // act
    var actual = TryValidate(sut, out results);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(actual);
}
```

Alternatively to using DataAnnotations you may take a look at [`FluentValidation.NET`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) which allows you to express much more complex validation rules in a fluent manner, it has a nice [`integration with MVC`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/MVC) and [`testing`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/Testing) your validation rules is even easier.

Comment: You can also use the controller by calling `MyController.Validate(sut)`. http://www.vannevel.net/2015/03/08/50/

Answer (score 1):

If you - for what ever reason - want to test, that a *property is annotated* (instead of testing that a validation annotation works), you can use the extension method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically) in your test:

```
public static T GetAttributeFrom<T>(this object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
{
    var attrType = typeof(T);
    var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (T)property .GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

EDITED: 
(1) used FirstOrDefault() instead of First() to correctly handle non-annotated attributes.
(2) @Pavel Straka: Added more sample code below to answer Pavel Straka's comment.

```
class Sample
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Year of Manufacture has to be filled")]
    public int? YearOfManufacture { get; set; }

    public int? NotAttributedProperty { get; set; }
}

static class Annotations
{
    public static T GetAttributeFrom<T>(this object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
    {
        var attrType = typeof(T);
        var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return (T)property.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sampleInstance = new Sample();
        var annotation = sampleInstance.GetAttributeFrom<RequiredAttribute>("YearOfManufacture");
        var nullAnnotation = sampleInstance.GetAttributeFrom<RequiredAttribute>("NotAttributedProperty");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error: System.Array does not contain a definition for First and no extension method First accepting a first argument of Type System.Array could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)? I can't add reference to System.Array. How could I solve this? Thank you