# Asp.net Unit test model data annotation DataType.EmailAddress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, data-annotations

How do I test `DataType.EmailAddress`?

I have a `Customer` model with an `Email` property with the following data annotations to validate:

```
[StringLength(100)]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email must be a valid email address")]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

I am writing unit tests to test validations. I have figured out how to test required and string length.

Here's my method that catches other errors, but doesn't handle the DataType validations:

```
private List<ValidationResult> ValidateModel<T>(T model)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, result, true);

    return result;
}
```

I call it in a test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Invalid_email_addresses_throw_errors()
{
    var model = new Models.Customer();

    model.email = "";
    var results = ValidateModel(model);
    Assert.IsTrue(results.Any(v => v.ErrorMessage == "Email is required"));
}
```

How do I test `DataType.EmailAddress` - passing in an invalid value and receiving the an error as a result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259793/how-would-you-unit-test-data-annotations

Comment: Hi Hackerman, I don't see how that helps me. I want to test the DataType.EmailAddress passing in an invalid value and catch the expected error message in the result. Thanks

Comment: There is no validation associated with a `[DataType]` attribute. Its for adding metadata that describes how to render the html (using `EditorFor(m => m.email) will add `type="email")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`[EmailAddress]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) DataTypeAttribute.

[EmailAddressAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) is derived from `DataTypeAttribute` and overrides the `IsValid` method which is what checks that the value is in fact a valid email.

Using

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email must be a valid email address")]
```

does not do anything for email validation.

If you inspect the source code for [DataTypeAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/DataTypeAttribute.cs) you will realize that it is primarily a base attribute used to create custom and targeted validation attribute.

The `DataTypeAttribute` in the original question is being used incorrectly.
There is no other solution than to use the `EmailAddressAttribute` as demonstrated below in the following unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestExample {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Invalid_email_addresses_throw_errors() {
        //Arrange
        var badEmail = "1234_)(";
        var subject = new Customer { email = badEmail };

        //Act
        var results = ValidateModel(subject);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Count > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Any(v => v.MemberNames.Contains("email")));
    }

    public class Customer {

        [StringLength(100)]            
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email must be a valid email address")]
        public string email { get; set; }

    }

    private List<ValidationResult> ValidateModel<T>(T model) {
        var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
        var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, result, true);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nkosi. This is a really nice solution for when you can alter the model. I maybe able to get it altered, but it belongs to another team and that make take some effort. I am hoping to see a solution that will test the the error that is thrown by the DataType.EmailAddress. As I work my way through building these unit tests, I am pretty sure I will have similar issues  for other data types.  Nonetheless, I appreciate this solution. Thanks

Comment: @deanblank there is no other solution. The DataTypeAttribute is being used incorrectly. The other team needs to change it.

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate you taking the time.